# Toast with custom message

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I start to learn Android programming, and now I try to display a toast with a custom string.

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(100 - 90 + 1) + 90;
String message = String.format(r);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "@".replace(message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting the following error message:

> Error:(40, 40) error: no suitable method found for format(Random) method String.format(String,Object...) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Random cannot be converted to String) method String.format(Locale,String,Object...) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Random cannot be converted to Locale)

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes. Error:(40, 40) error: no suitable method found for format(Random)
method String.format(String,Object...) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Random cannot be converted to String)
method String.format(Locale,String,Object...) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Random cannot be converted to Locale)

Comment: @Joe I guess you wanted to display `i`, so you have to put it in `String.format()` rather than your `Random` object, like `String message = String.format(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you've found the answer yourself, I still want to provide some examples to make sure that you understand how `String#format(String, Object...)` works:

```
Random r = new Random();
String message = null;

int i = r.nextInt(100 - 90 + 1) + 90;
message = String.format("%d", i);

float f = 0.1;
message = String.format("%f", f);

String s = "Hello world";
message = String.format("%s", s);

// "Hello world, f=0.1"
message = String.format("%s, f=%f", s, f);
```

More explanation about java formatting can be reached at:

- [Formatter (Java Platform SE 7 ) - Oracle Help Center](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)
- [The Java™ Tutorials - Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Looks like `int` cannot be converted to `String`.

So this fixed my problem:

```
Random r = new Random();
int i = r.nextInt(100 - 90 + 1) + 90;
String message = String.format(Integer.toString(i));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```